# make text highlighted red & bold if criteria is met?

Tags: formula, formatting, text

i have a requirement that if my text field has a certain value it should be displayed highlighted red and bold. at first thought i'm thinking i have to change the field type to a formula field that returns text. and then enter an IF formula expression? am i approaching this right..

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now Salesforce doesn't support conditional formatting of field values even for formula fields. This is still in Idea stage https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrPbAAK.

Only rich text fields support formatting. Here is a [Success Commuity Link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iXz3QAE) similar to the requirement where a custom rich text area field is used instead of a formula field and the field value is updated with HTML formatting using a workflow field update.

> Update

First Create a Rich Text Area and then Create a Field update as below with a similar formula to update this Rich Text Area. Now fire this field update with a workflow rule.

```
IF(Amount < 100000 ,('<html><body><div style="color: red;"><b>' & TEXT(Amount) & '</b></div></body></html>'),
IF(Amount > 100000 ,('<html><body><div style="color: green;"><b>' & TEXT(Amount) & '</b></div></body></html>'),
""
))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ok so i changed the type to rich text field, and started to build a field update workflow rule with the correct criteria but not sure how to enter the formula here under specify new field value. i need it to be bold and red/highlighted in red. the links you provided led to "<html><body><div style="color: red;"><b>text</b></div></body></html>" but that's not proper syntax?

Comment: @david Please see my updated answer.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not Exactly the answer but very useful and can be adapted

Here is a Formula Text Field with an Image:

```
CASE( TEXT(Rating__c),
   "1", IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "RED", 20, 20),
   "2", IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif", "YELLOW", 20, 20),
   "3", IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif", "GREEN", 20, 20)
   ),
   "n/a"
)
```